# How to identify transient errors in NET Standard 2.1 with MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mysql.data, transient-failure

I'm writing my app with NET Standard 2.1 and MySql (NuGet pack MySql.Data).
The MySqlException doesn't have the property IsTransient so I can't recognize if the exception is temporary. How can I manage this? Is there a list of error code that are transient? I can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If switching NuGet packages is an option for you, the [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) package (disclaimer: I'm the lead author) implements this property: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/849

Otherwise, you could borrow [its logic](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/855149dcb01659fbddd5127ed0919dfa6e4412e0/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlException.cs#L117-L122):

```cs
public static bool IsTransient(MySqlException ex) => (MySqlErrorCode) ex.Code
    is MySqlErrorCode.ConnectionCountError
    or MySqlErrorCode.LockDeadlock
    or MySqlErrorCode.LockWaitTimeout
    or MySqlErrorCode.UnableToConnectToHost
    or MySqlErrorCode.XARBDeadlock
```